# Get data between number two and three delimiter

Tags: google-sheets

I have a large list of people where each person has a line like this.

```
Bill Gates, IT Manager, Microsoft, <https://www.linkedin.com/in/williamhgates>
```

I want to extract the company name in a specific cell. In this example, it would be Microsoft, which is between the second and third delimiters (in this case, the delimiter is `", "`). How can I do this?

Right now I'm using the split method (`=SPLIT(A2, ", ",false)`). But it gives me four different cells with information. I would like a command only to output the company in one cell. Can anyone help? I have tried different things, but I can't seem to find anything that works.

Maybe some regex can do it, but I'm not into regex.

Comment: Tags fixed, it's for google-spreadsheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short answer

Use INDEX and SPLIT to get the value between two separators. Example

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(A1,", ",FALSE),2)
```

## Explation

- SPLIT returns an 1 x n array.
- The first argument of INDEX could be a range or an array.
- The second and third arguments of INDEX are optional. If the first parameter is an array that has only one row or one column, it will assume that the second argument corresponds to the larger side of the array, so there is no need to use the third argument.

Answer (score 0):

A bit nasty, but this formula works, assuming data in cell D3.

```
=MID(D3,FIND(",",D3,FIND(",",D3)+1)+2,FIND(",",D3,FIND(",",D3,FIND(",",D3)+1)+1)-FIND(",",D3,FIND(",",D3)+1)-2)
```

Broken down, this is what it does:

- Take the Mid point of D3 `=MID(D3`
- starting two characters after the 2nd comma `FIND(",",D3,FIND(",",D3)+1)+2`
- and the number of characters between the 2nd and 3rd comma, excluding spaces `FIND(",",D3,FIND(",",D3,FIND(",",D3)+1)+1)-FIND(",",D3,FIND(",",D3)+1)-2)`

Answer (score 0):

I'll add my favourite ArratFormula, which you could use to expand list automatically without draggind formula down. Assumptions:

1. you have list with data in range "A1:A20"
2. all data have same sintax "...,Company Name, <..."

In this case you could use Arrayformula, pasted in cell B1:

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A20,", ([^,]+), <"))
```

---

If your data doest's always look like "...,Company Name, <..." or you wish to get different ounput, use this formula in cell B1:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(", ",A1:A20),", ",0)),"offset 2"),"skipping 4")
```

in this formula:

- change 2 in `offset 2` to 0, 1, 2, 3 to get name, position, company, link
- in `skipping 4` 4 is a number of items.

Number of items can be counted by formula:

```
=len(A1)-len(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))+1
```

and final formula is:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(", ",A1:A20),", ",0)),"offset 2"),
"skipping "&len(A1)-len(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))+1)
```